# What should I pass as a parameter to getEnabled()?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, vsto, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have created a call back method `getEnabled = Get2DButtonEnable` the method is shown below

```
public bool bolEnabled;

//load the UI for the addin
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
    this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    bolEnabled = true;
}

public bool Get2DButtonEnable(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool enabled)
{
    switch (control.Id)
    {
        case "btn2d": 
            enabled = bolEnabled; 
            break;                
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now i want to call this method inside another method in different class.
I created instance of the ribbon class and trying to call this method in the other class like `visRibbon.Get2DButtonEnable()`. What should I pass the parameter to this method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Ribbon.InvalidateContol("btn2d")`
This will force to call all the events associated with control **btn2d**.

More in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol%28v=office.15%29.aspx)